# Xpath sibling conditional testing?

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm using VB.net (2003), and calling the SelectNodes method on an xml document.
If I have a document:

```
<InqRs>  
  <DetRs>  
    <RefInfo>  
      <RefType>StopNum</RefType>  
      <RefId>0</RefId>  
    </RefInfo>  
    <RefInfo>  
      <RefType>Id</RefType>  
      <RefId>0</RefId>  
    </RefInfo>  
  </DetRs>  
  <DetRs>  
    <RefInfo>  
      <RefType>StopNum</RefType>  
      <RefId>0</RefId>  
    </RefInfo>  
    <RefInfo>  
      <RefType>Id</RefType>  
      <RefId>1</RefId>  
    </RefInfo>  
  </DetRs>  
</InqRs>
```

How can I select just for the `DetRs` that has `RefType=Id` and `RefId=0`, ie, the 'first' one above?

I've tried several different attempts, among others:

```
InqRs/DetRs[RefInfo/RefType='Id' and RefInfo/RefId='0']  
InqRs/DetRs[RefInfo/RefType='Id'][RefInfo/RefId='0']
```

But these select both of the DetRs sections (because of the StopNum 
RefId of 0, I presume).

Comment: @Mark: You can accept the best answer by clicking on the (white) checkmark next to your question.

Answer (score 3):

You want all **`DetRs`** children of the top element:

`/*/DetRs`

That have a **`RefInfo`** child:

`/*/DetRs`
             `[RefInfo]`

That has **`RefType`** with value "**`Id`**":

`/*/DetRs`
             `[RefInfo`
                   [`RefType`='`Id`']
              ]

and that has a **`RefId`** with value **0**:

`/*/DetRs`
             `[RefInfo`
                   [`RefType`='`Id`'

                 `and`
                   `RefId`=0
                   ]
              ]

**And this XPath expression correctly selects just the wanted first `DetRs` element in the provided XML document**.

Certainly, if someone has other stylistic preferences, the above expression could be written also as:

**`/*/DetRs[RefInfo[RefType='Id' and RefId=0]]`**

Answer (score 1):

Like so. You don't need the top-level InqRs in your XPath expression, though it doesn't hurt. You may not care about the DetRs either, but assuming you do, you want to say "give me the parent of the Refinfo element which has the following specification"

```
DetRs/Refinfo[RefType='Id' and RefId='0']/..
```